# Meaning of entries in /etc/securetty?

Tags: security, root, terminal, tty

I've been given a set of entries to apply to /etc/securetty, what does each of them mean?

```
console
tty1cd /
tty2
tty3
tty4
tty5
tty6
ttyS0
ttyS1
```

I'm especially interested in the "tty1cd /" entry.  I can't find anything about it online, and nobody here seems to know why it's there...

Comment: I strongly suspect it's the result of someone typing `cd /`, intending to talk to a shell, but accidentally typing it into an edit window instead.

Comment: I guess it could well be.  I've seen some mentions of "ttycd" on my question to find the answer, leading me to think that "ttycd /" might have been a legitimate entry.

Comment: Why don't you ask whoever gave you the list to confirm that it's correct as the line you cite seems incorrect.

Comment: That would be nice - but the people who compiled the list have moved on. All anyone seems to know is that this is the 'approved list'.

Comment: looks like you're going to have to go through the approval process again then

Comment: ...are you asking "what does `/etc/securetty` do?", or are you asking "Did some idjit make a typo in the list they gave me?" (The answer to the former is [`man securetty`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/securetty), the answer to the latter is ["Almost certainly yes!"](http://serverfault.com/a/596932/32986))

Comment: @voretaq7, the question was "what does each entry mean?" - the answer would then allow me to understand the contents of the file, and as a byproduct assess what should/shouldn't be there.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include that.

Comment: If you'd read the man page the meaning would be fairly obvious :(

Comment: @Iain, would you mind specifying which man page to look at, as in RHEL6 the man page for securetty(5), and tty(4). Didn't seem to mention what entries meant, or point to where such information could be found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tty1cd /` is definitely a typo of `tty1` and `cd /`, so I would replace it with just `tty1`.

Other than that, your `/etc/securetty` seems fine.

**Update** This file defines terminals on (from) which root can login. The names in it map to `/dev/<name>` virtual terminals. Reasonable system should have the appropriate man page `securetty(5)` (accessible vie e.g. `man securetty`) where you'll find more information.